# Pyspark saveAsTextFile fails while data frame writers succeed

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

TLDR: Calling `saveAsTextFile` on an `rdd` fails with `FileOutputCommitter` not found while saving from a data frame via `write.format(...).save(...)` works and makes use of `FileOutputCommitter`. The problem seems environment related in that I can perform this action in one environment (local) but cannot in a, presumably, similar environment (aws emr). Configurations are, as far as I can tell, the same.

Scenario:

- Local install of Spark 2.0 (via home brew) and Hadoop 2.7.2 (via home brew)
- AWS EMR 5.0 cluster with Spark 2.0 and Hadoop 2.7.2
- Modified `mapred-site.xml` to include:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version</name>
      <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>spark.hadoop.mapred.output.committer.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.class</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>mapred.output.committer.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.class</value>
  </property>
  ```

Added the correct `jars` to `spark-default.conf` with `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath`. This setup is confirmed in the "Environment" tab of the spark web ui.

Problem Repro Local (OS X) works fine:

```
In [2]: df = [tuple(range(3))]

In [3]: df = spark.createDataFrame([tuple(range(3))], ['one', 'two', 'three'])

In [4]: df.show()
+---+---+-----+
|one|two|three|
+---+---+-----+
|  0|  1|    2|
+---+---+-----+


In [5]: df.rdd.saveAsTextFile('test_output.txt')

In [6]: df.write.format('csv').save('test_output.csv')
```

Problem Repro AWS EMR:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([tuple(range(3))], ['one', 'two', 'three'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+-----+
|one|two|three|
+---+---+-----+
|  0|  1|    2|
+---+---+-----+

>>> df.write.format('csv').save('test_output.csv')
>>> df.rdd.saveAsTextFile('test_output.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1519, in saveAsTextFile
    keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.saveAsTextFile.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.class not found
```

My intuition here is that I have a configuration difference between the two scenarios. The dataframe save calls on EMR are using `FileOutputCommitter` as the logs indicate so `jar` is provided properly. Under the hood `saveAsTextFile` calls `saveAsHadoopFile` and I'm not sure if the dataframe writers do that.

Anyone have a clue as to where in my configurations I should be looking to help `saveAsTextFile` find the supplied `jar`? Is this a non-obvious hadoop misconfiguration?

Comment: what happens if you just create rdd (not df.rdd) and try to save it?

Comment: Same error. If I make `test_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([tuple(range(3))])` and then `test_rdd.saveAsTextFile('test_rdd_save.txt')` it fails on emr with same error and succeeds locally.

Comment: In that case, look into spark-env and spark default conf for classpath. Or, you may want to search the class name, find out which jar it belongs to, find that jar in your EMR system and pass it using --jars switch

Comment: The jar is in the class path and I can confirm this via the spark UI. I'll try jars arg but this is not needed in the local scenario so it seems unlikely it'll change the remote.